# Visual Studio breaking without a breakpoint in a VB project?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Running a particular project in Debug, Visual Studio is always stopping at the `Public Sub New()` line in my main form (it's an older project, so the code is within a autogenerated region in the .vb file rather than a .designer.vb file). No idea why this is happening and it's becoming a headache. It doesn't happen in any of my other VB projects (or running under Release). I can just hit F5 and it continues as normal.

Things I have tried:

- Debug > Delete all breakpoints
- Deleting the .suo file

I should note that both before and after doing the above, there is no breakpoint symbol next to the line. The execution just pauses and the line gets highlighted with a yellow arrow, as with a normal breakpoint line.
Why would VS be breaking at this opening line even without any breakpoints? I'm pretty sure I deleted the relevant files, so I would guess there's a VS setting I can't seem to find (but if it's a setting, wouldn't it affect other projects as well?).

Also, there are multiple developers working on this project. I am the only one this happens to.

Comment: Does it log anything in the Immediate/Output Window when it breaks?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the the "bin" and "obj" folders.  Do this outside of VS with the project closed.  Then open the project and rebuild.

Comment: @VisualVincent - Nothing out of the ordinary (loading dlls and such).

Comment: @TnTinMn - No dice

Comment: Any .sdf file? Delete it too

Comment: @djv - Nope, no .sdf file.

Comment: You stated "Deleting the .suo file", but since this project started out as a early VS project it obviously went through an _upgrade_ at one time.  Which ".suo" file did you delete?  There could be the original one "soultion name.suo" and the one buried under the ".vs" directory.

Comment: @TnTinMn - All of them. I searched the directory for anything matching *.suo (including hidden) and deleted (with VS closed of course).

Comment: @DangerZone, Do you mean that the same app has no this issue in other VS machine? If you reset your VS settings, and then debug your app again, how about the result? Please compare the options under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General, if it works well in other VS machine, please compare yours with other VS settings, maybe you could find the differences. In addition, make sure that it has no Exception throw, also view the output window, and find more useful information.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT : I already asked him about the Immediate and Output Window... Apparently nothing special is logged.

Comment: @DangerZone is it only in this project or general VS issue? did you check yours Exception settings? Maybe you have an option to break "when exception is thrown"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that "Enable Just My Code" was turned off in my debug settings.

I'm still not entirely sure why that caused it to break at this particular line without a breakpoint attached (other projects don't break here, even my fellow developer didn't have this issue after matching his settings with mine and debugging the same project...), but after checking this option, it no longer breaks at that first line.

Comment: One possible reason is that it was related to the non-user code which has an Exception: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/JustMyCode.aspx, anyway since it was resolved, you could mark it as the answer later:)

Comment: Would you please mark your solution as the answer? So it could help other community members who meet the same issue.

Comment: It occurred the issue on my project - ASP.NET MVC.
After reading the answer, I checked 'Enable Just My Code' option.
![](https://i.imgur.com/xsGIuxM.png)
But it did not resolve of breaking without a breakpoint